# Can I restore file in Visual Studio project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

My project consist of three files: 'class.h', 'outside.h' and 'main.cpp'. The code in the file 'main.cpp' is the most important.

Yesterday I compiled the project in debug mode. Today I've opened it and found that file 'main.cpp' is empty. More exactly, it contains 6 KB of 'NIL' symbols.

All debug information and exeсutable file is saved. Can I restore the file? I use VS Express 2015.

Comment: That's why you should use some sort of version control.

Comment: Thanks. I will use something,

Comment: And if you don't find other simple reason for this (such as your own program accidentaly writing to `main.cpp`), make full backup of your hard drive, it may be failing.

Comment: Thanks. I will remember it.

Comment: You might be lucky and find something in the following location: `\...\My Documents\Visual Studio <version>\Backup Files\<projectname>`.

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no--Visual Studio doesn't back up any files. I'd highly recommend storing your code in some kind of version control system (such as Git, SVN, etc)--search the web for some free providers.

Comment: Actually, there *is* a feature for saving snapshots. It has to be enabled in advance though and it *is* heavier than using version control